# Calculate the sum of a field from shapefiles and copy these values to a new table

Tags: arcpy, cursor

I have a number of shapefiles, the attribute table of each  one has a FLOAT field called "Relative_W". I need to create a table that displays the summation of "Relative_W" for all the shapefiles. ANY HELP?

the shape files attribute as this
[image]

Unfortunately, the new table is always empty
[image]

here is my code.

```
# Create the Table to be filled with the summations
arcpy.env.workspace=r'C:\ModelBuilder\AAA\New Folder (17)\Flash Flood Risk Assessment Projcet\FFRA_WRRI.gdb'
fctble=arcpy.CreateTable_management(arcpy.env.workspace,"Scenarious_Comparison")
arcpy.AddField_management(fctble, "Scenario", "TEXT", field_length = 8)
arcpy.AddField_management(fctble, "Risk_Indicator", "FLOAT")

for i in range (0,2):
    sum = 0
    fc ='Risk_Scenario_%d' %i # the shape files that I need to read and sum its value
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, "Relative_W") as cursor: # Relative_W the field of needed data
        for row in cursor:
            if row[0] is not None:
                sum = sum + row[0] # This is the summation value. 
                                   # NOW, I need to add this value to the generated empty table "fctble"
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fctble,["Scenario","Risk_Indicator"]) as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
                cursor.updateRow([i,summed_total])
```

Comment: It may be easier to find the sum for each shapefile with `val = sum(row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fctble, "Relative_W") if row[0] != None)`.

Comment: Do you think, I need to add something like`row = rows.next()`

Comment: The code that you have presented looks more like a copy/paste from your code instead of a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) that you have developed to illustrate a problem in your code.  It may be easier to find the sum for each shapefile using Summary Statistics.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the wrong variables when updating your rows. You call i, but your iterator is named row. In this part of the code is also no variable called summed_total.

Try `cursor.updateRow([row,sum])`